# enum flags with name

Tags: c++, enums, flags, enum-flags

I'm going to use enum flags for options to initialize my class. The enum is:

```
namespace MCXJS
{
    enum VARPARAM
    {
        STATIC = 1,
        CONST = 2
    }

    //other things
}
```

If I'm right, in this case, to check for STATIC I need to do this:

```
if (param & MCXJS::VARPARAM::STATIC) //...
```

I know to do it this way:

```
if (param & MCXJS::STATIC) //...
```

i need to delete enum name. But it that really necessary? Cannot I use enum values of named enum without typing its name everywhere?

Comment: The correct way to name `STATIC` _is_ `MCXJS::STATIC`, not `MCXJS::VARPARAM::STATIC`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh? You don't need to prefix it with the enumeration name. That's only needed for C++0x `enum class` scoped enumerations.